# periodic digits and numprint

Tags: accents, numprint

I want to use numprint to add separators every three digits of a decimal representation of a rational BUT with an overline over the repeating digits.

For example, for the unitary fraction 1/42, I get:

[image: 1/42]

without numprint and I want numprint spaces.

I mention that the number is constructed within pythontex concatenating integer part, irregular part and finally repeating part with overline.

**edit**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}[dvt]
from dvtDecimal import *
\end{pycode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[dvt]
f = dvtDecimal(1, 42) 
print("$" + f.toTeX()[2] + "$")
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

and the python code looks like this:
[image]

Comment: ...okay... so what does the input look like?

Comment: What's a "numprint space"? Please elaborate.

Comment: [numprint](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint) is a package to separate digits.
Maybe, I'd better put some LaTeX spaces \, every 3 digits directly in the python code instead... But as numprint is language sensitive, I thought it should be the first thing to try.

Comment: Why adding the Python code as an image? And where's it supposed to be used? I get `ImportError: No module named dvtDecimal`.